# Instagram changed policy to retrieve posts with hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram has changed policy since June 1st. Now my code which used to fetch posts with certain hashtag in a website stopped working.

According to this [new policy](http://developers.instagram.com/post/145262544121/instagram-platform-update-effective-june-1-2016), the app needs to submit for approval. But when i went through approval process, the privacy policy is a must and which should describes how this app would use data. and when i went through [sample instagram policy](http://www.grabapp.co/legal/privacypolicy.html) this is huge and mostly deals with mobile app.

Now my qeustion is, do i need to write something like this when my app just needs to use client id's secret keys and general stuff just to fetch posts with certain(defined) hastag ?

I have used [instafeed.js](http://instafeedjs.com/) to retrieve posts by hashtag.

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: "<?php echo $tagname;?>",
        clientId: "<?php echo $client_id;?>",
        limit: 14,
        template: '<a href="#"><img data-attr="{{id}}" src="{{image}}" alt="{{caption}}" data-username="{{link}}" /></a>',
    });
```

**UPDATE :**

It looks like we won't be able to fetch particular hashtagged public content in our website.

[image]

Also, in the alert section **As alternative solution, ..... find a *company* that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).**

What are these company instagram talked about ?

Comment: I think you need to ask Instagram's support/helpdesk.  Any answer you get from the random users on StackOverflow will be unofficial at best.

Comment: There is no IG help desk that I know of, they actually refer you here (https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/). I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

We're in the same boat. The only one I've found so far that claims to be able to do this is called Dialog Feed. Here is their blog post about it: https://www.dialogfeed.com/instagram-api-not-working-solutions-for-hashtag-and-profile-search/
They are not cheap, however. Like 890 eur/year not cheap for just the basic.